How can you conditionally render components on a page and use routing together?
I took a previously working page that conditionally rendered components and tried to add routing via react-routerv6. It's neither updating the URI nor the page when I try to change the selectedComponent via the webpage. I'm not getting an error in the console during build or chrome console. Is the problem that I'm trying to use routing on a component within App.js?
App.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div>
      <div>
        <DrawerAndAppBar
          handleButtonClick={handleButtonClick}
          listItemName={listItemName}
        />
      </div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          {selectedComponent === 'LimitsDataGrid' && (
            <Route
              exact
              path='/LIMITS/:listItemName'
              element={<LimitsDataGrid listItemName={listItemName} />}
            />
          )}
          {selectedComponent === 'MyDashboard' && (
            <Route
              exact
              path='/DASH/:listItemName'
              element={(
                <MyDashboard
                  listItemName={listItemName}
                  onComponentChange={handleButtonClick}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
          {selectedComponent === 'LotDrillDown' && (
            <Route
              exact
              path='/LOTVIEW/:listItemName/:lotID'
              element={(
                <LotDrillDown
                  listItemName={listItemName}
                  lotID={lotID}
                  onComponentChange={handleButtonClick}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;


What is selectedComponent? Where and how are you effecting navigation actions, and where are you navigating to? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with? I think you have some misunderstandings. The routes are what conditionally render their elements based on the URL, navigating to the specific paths is what is matched by the router and the matching route content is rendered.
